# Is the crossing number of the line graph of $K_5$ determined?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-drawing

The **line graph** of an undirected graph $G$ is another graph $L(G)$ that represents the adjacencies between edges of $G$. $L(G)$ is constructed in the following way: for each edge in $G$, make a vertex in $L(G)$; for every two edges in $G$ that have a vertex in common, make an edge between their corresponding vertices in $L(G)$.

I would like to know the crossing number of a line graph of a complete graph $K_5$.  Furthermore, what is crossing-minimal drawing of $L(K_5)$?

Here's what I know now and that's about it.

- **$L(K_5)$ has crossing numer 3 or more.**

We can see above result in following paper.

- Kulli V R, Akka D G, Beineke L W. On line graphs with crossing number 1[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 1979, 3(1): 87-90.]

Ps: We see easily that $L(K_5)$ is the complement of Petersen graph.

Comment: To compute the crossing number of a specific graph such as $L(K_5)$, you can try the [CRWC](http://crossings.uos.de/).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to learn how to use this software. It doesn't look easy run. I tried to apply for it, but my email never received the verification message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for advice from **Timothy Chow**. I have now received an email from [CRWS](http://crossings.uos.de/). The graph has a crossing number of 12.

[image]
[image]

Its crossing-minimal drawing is as follows.
[image: ![enter image description here]